# How do I install minecraft 1.9 on mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I install minecraft 1.9 on mac? I have looked at the option slider and it goes only up to 1.8.8 how do I get 1.9?

Comment: 1.9 hasn't been released yet, mate.

Comment: well he probably meant **snapshot**

Comment: Yea I meant the snapshot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Minecraft is now officially has its versions up to 1.8.8.

1.9 is not offically released yet, but **snapshots** came out. If you were referring to the snapshots, do the following.

In your launcher, click <kbd>Edit Profile</kbd> and scroll down the <kbd>Use Version</kbd> tab. Be sure to tick the **Enable Experimental development verions (snapshots)** before you go to the <kbd>Use Verson</kbd> tab. Click the **latest** snapshot, which is ***snapshot* 15w33b** (as of today).

You can now make a world and test out the upcoming 1.9 version of Minecraft!

### Warning

After making your "1.9" world, **do not** enter the world with a **1.8**
 account as it may corrupt the world.

Everything you see in that **snapshot** is not confirmed. And **may** change during the process of making **1.9**.